# epoll_wait and build_trtable consume too much cpu

Tags: c++, linux, epoll

epoll_wait and build_trtable is consuming too much of my cpu, here is the flame graph.
[flame graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayfBR.png)

The blue part is my running function, as you can see, the cpu is doing other things like epoll_wait and build_trtalbe and others.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I use the raw packet to recieve packet from the interfaces. there are three threads in my process. The main thread  recieves the packet from the raw packets and puts them into to two queues. The other two thread takes packets from their queue and handle the packets.

Comment: The question is I can only use limited cpu, but now the process is consuming more cpu than expected.

Comment: You need to show the relevant parts, i.e. are you using `EPOLLONESHOT`?